# Having trouble indexing directories with whitespaces

Tags: bash

This script almost works as it should, scanning for directories containing a word, but.. If the directory contains a whitespace, it indexes the path of the directory separately in the array.. Anyone know what needs to be changed in this script for it to properly snag the whole directory even with spaces?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the word you want to search for:"
read word

echo "Directories containing the word $word are:"
dirs=($(find /folder -type d -name "*$word*" -print0 | awk -v RS='\0' '{print $0}'))
for i in "${!dirs[@]}"; do
    echo "$i: ${dirs[$i]}"
done

echo "Enter the number of the directory you want to delete:"
read num

dir=${dirs[$num]}

if [ -z "$dir" ]
then
    echo "Invalid input"
else
    echo "Are you sure you want to delete $dir? (y/n)"
    read ans
    if [ "$ans" == "y" ]
    then
        rm -rf "$dir"
        echo "$dir has been deleted"
    else
        echo "Deletion cancelled"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Your `awk { print $0 }` cancels the protective effect of `find ... -print0 | awk -v RS='\0'`.  The net effect is as if you just had `find ... -print` without any `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the directory contains a whitespace, it indexes the path of the directory separately in the array

Yes.  This is because the results of the command substitution `$(find ... | awk ...)` are split on runs of spaces, tabs, and / or newlines to yield the words with which to initialize array `dirs`.  I guess you were trying to use `find`'s `-print0` action to avoid that, but you've mooted that effect by undoing it with `awk`.

As an alternative, consider the `mapfile` builtin (a.k.a. `readarray`).  It will map lines read from its input to array elements, which seems to be exactly what you're after:

```
mapfile -t dirs < <(find /folder -type d -name "*${word}*")
for i in "${!dirs[@]}"; do
    echo "$i: ${dirs[$i]}"
done
```

Notes:

- the `-t` option removes the trailing newline from each line read, so that these do not appear in the array elements.
- The input is provided via a process substitution instead of via a pipe to avoid `mapfile` running in a subshell, which would moot the whole exercise.

Comment: This worked 100%, thank you for informing me on mapfile! :-)

Comment: The (non-working) `-print0` attempt of the OP also presumably has the purpose to deal with filenames which have a newline in them. They would now be split into several pieces by your approach. Do you see a way to combine the benefits of `mapfile`+process substitution, and using NUL as separator for catching newlines?

Comment: @user1934428 `mapfile -d ''` for bash >= 4.3, or a `while IFS='' read -r -d ''` for older bash